# trying to plot a gear curve in gnuplot

Tags: functions, graphing-functions, parametric

Im looking at this [gear curve:](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GearCurve.html) thinking wow I'd like to plot that!
so then I tried, in c++, with gnuplot.

```
/*
the gear curve is a curve resembling a gear with n teeth given by the parametric equations
x   =   r*cos*t 
y   =   r*sin*t,    

where
r=a+1/b*tanh[b*sin(n*t)],   

where tanhx is the hyperbolic tangent. Plots above show gear curves for a=1, b=10, and n=1 to 12. */
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;
int main(){

    ofstream plot;
    plot.open("plotz.dat");

    double r = 1;
    int t = 0; //theta, might need to be an itterator.
    double a = 1.1;
    double b = 10;
    double xx = r*cos(t);
    double yy = r*sin(t);
    //cout << "Sine 45: " << sin(45) << endl;
    for(t=1;t <= 360; t+=1){
    r = a+(1/b)*tanh(b*sin(12*t));

    xx = r*cos(t);
    yy = r*sin(t);
//cout << r << " " << xx << " " << yy << " " <<  endl;
plot << r << " " << xx << " " << yy << " " <<  endl;
}
    plot.close();
    return 0;
    }
```

but instead of the nice smooth curve of the gear plot, I get something that is only vaguely similar.[image]

I would like to get these sweet gear curves:
[image]

where did I go wrong? how can I get output that looks like that?

Comment: Does the sine function take degrees as input? I suspect that you may have to use radians.

Comment: Nice, catch! @JohnDouma, I just added a  rad =(t*pi)/180; variable, and changed the inputs of the sin and cosine functions, and it works great! https://imgur.com/a/uD6IjW1